# how to implement expect "interact" command using java

Tags: java, unix, tcl, expect, expectj

I want to implement the expect "interact" command using java. In expect, it's possible to open an ssh session, authenticate and, then, use the "interact" command to give the control back to the user. Is that possible with java? I've tried with expectJ, expect4J and expectForJava but there's little documentation and almost no examples of how to do this. TIA.

Update: for "interact" command reference, please check this out: http://wiki.tcl.tk/3914

> "Interact is an Expect command which gives control of the current
>   process to the user, so that keystrokes are sent to the current
>   process, and the stdout and stderr of the current process are
>   returned."

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/expect4j/wiki/Installation perhaps here?

Comment: @SergeyBenner I could not find in expect4J, from the Java code, someone can call the "interact" command. The Expect object does only have "expect" and "send" methods. expectJ does have one explicitly, but it does not work (or I don't know how to use it properly).

Comment: @DaveJarvis I would like to take a look. Did you wrote it from the scratch or did you use any existent lib? Does it have the "interact" functionality?

Comment: @LeonardoKenji: Try this https://bitbucket.org/djarvis/jexpect

Comment: Expect's `interact` is pretty high up the secret-sauce scale. Good luck! (It uses a lot of the funkier details of Unix virtual terminals in order to hook the one that the user is on to the one that the spawned application is on. It's also _really rarely implemented_ except in the original Expect.)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested, I have added basic interactive loop support to [ExpectIt](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt), my own open source Expect for Java implementation (sorry for self-promotion), since version 0.8.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt/blob/master/expect-java8/src/main/java/net/sf/expectit/java8/Java8Example.java) of interacting with the system input stream in Java 8:

```
        try (final Expect expect = new ExpectBuilder()
                .withInputs(System.in)
                .build()) {
            expect.interact()
                    .when(contains("abc")).then(r -> System.out.println("A"))
                    .when(contains("xyz")).then(r -> System.err.println("B"))
                    .until(contains("exit"));
            System.out.println("DONE!");
        }
        System.in.close();
```

Comment: Hi Alexey - Really appreciate expectit - currently trying to get interact working.  What is "r" in this example?

Comment: @JonA 'r' is a lambda function parameter.  Try to play with the complete example: https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt/blob/master/expect-java8/src/main/java/net/sf/expectit/java8/Java8Example.java

Comment: I'm using maven dependency, contains not resolved for me.. why idea?

Comment: @Udhaya which version are you trying to use? This works find for me
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.expectit</groupId>
        <artifactId>expectit-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

These libraries might suit your needs better:

**SSHJ**

https://github.com/shikhar/sshj

**JSCH**

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/